# Reactflow - Background displaying over nodes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-flow

Using reactflow, on a simple graph I am trying to use the `<Background/>` Reactflow component as follows :

```
import React, { useCallback, useState } from 'react';
import ReactFlow, {
    addEdge,
    FitViewOptions,
    applyNodeChanges,
    applyEdgeChanges,
    Node,
    Edge,
    NodeChange,
    EdgeChange,
    Connection,
    Background,
    BackgroundVariant,
} from 'reactflow';

interface CreateGraphProps {

}

const initialNodes: Node[] = [
    { id: '1', data: { label: 'Node 1' }, position: { x: 5, y: 5 } },
    { id: '2', data: { label: 'Node 2' }, position: { x: 5, y: 100 } },
];

const initialEdges: Edge[] = [{ id: 'e1-2', source: '1', target: '2' }];

const fitViewOptions: FitViewOptions = {
    padding: 0.2,
};

export const CreateGraph: React.FC<CreateGraphProps> = ({ }) => {
    const [nodes, setNodes] = useState<Node[]>(initialNodes);
    const [edges, setEdges] = useState<Edge[]>(initialEdges);

    const onNodesChange = useCallback(
        (changes: NodeChange[]) => setNodes((nds) => applyNodeChanges(changes, nds)),
        [setNodes]
    );
    const onEdgesChange = useCallback(
        (changes: EdgeChange[]) => setEdges((eds) => applyEdgeChanges(changes, eds)),
        [setEdges]
    );
    const onConnect = useCallback(
        (connection: Connection) => setEdges((eds) => addEdge(connection, eds)),
        [setEdges]
    );

    return (
        <div>
            <ReactFlow
                nodes={nodes}
                edges={edges}
                onNodesChange={onNodesChange}
                onEdgesChange={onEdgesChange}
                onConnect={onConnect}
                attributionPosition='bottom-right'
                fitView
                fitViewOptions={fitViewOptions}>
                    <Background color='#a6a6a6' variant={'dots' as BackgroundVariant}/>
            </ReactFlow>

        </div>

    );
}
```

Without the background, the `OnConnect`, `onEdgesChanges` and `onNodesChange` functions work well. However, with the background it is not the case. The nodes can't be moved when the Background component is present.

Upon further investigation it seems that the `background` component is placed above the reactflow canvas. Is there somthing missing, prohibiting it from functionning properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found an answer that works for me, to get theming to work you need to import:

```
import 'reactflow/dist/style.css';
```

This can be used as a base theme to get started. [Docs are here](https://reactflow.dev/docs/guides/theming/).